# Anosim vs Permanova: What are their suitability when computing differences between groups?

Tags: biostatistics, group-differences, anosim

I am back with more questions, this time about multivariate analysis. As before I am new to this all so apologies in advance if the question is not well formulated.

**The problem**

We are trying to measure how a field of corals recovered over a number of years after a natural disaster occurred. For that we have abundance data of a number of coral species carefully observed in a certain site along a number of years. Years are listed as A, B, C...F.

So these species are our variables and their cover in some defined transects the values of such variables. We also have one categorical factor which is the year in which such data was recorded.

**The aim of the study**

The study was conducted by scientists a long time ago before Permanova was invented, early in the 80's. The aim was to check the change in the species composition along the years. Although a further study was done to determine the contribution of each species to those changes, **the main idea is to test whether there were significant differences between the composition of species year on year**.

**Multivariate Analysis done**
The authors at the time ran Anosim to check for the significance of the difference between years. To do so they did a pair-wise test. I am reproducing the same but by using Permanova instead.

**The Assumption**

Below you can see the attached images for Permanova and Anosim permanova results, done with Primer-7. I have also read the paper "The Application of multivariate statistical techniques in microbial ecology" that can be found here [Paliy_ME2016.pdf](http://www.wright.edu/%7Eoleg.paliy/Papers/Paliy_ME2016.pdf). **In such paper, if I understood well the difference between Anosim and Permanova is that the first tests for the differences within group vs between groups, while Permanova tests for how significance the difference is between groups.**

**The Questions**

a) If my assumption is correct, Anosim is showing the difference between groups by finding a bigger difference between groups than within the groups, while Permanova check outright for the difference between groups? I would find the latter more appropriate in this case?

b) Both Anosim and Permanova yield similar results with the latter being "more aggressive" in its conclusions as Permanova shows significance difference among all pair-wise comparison, with obviously, different gradients of significance. I understand they are different calculations, but my struggle lays in the fact that I am unable to explain what is it I am after with Anosim. I find this method more suitable if I wanted to check the recover year-on-year vs within-the-year but this is not the case. It feels like we are bending the hand of Anosim for our own purpose. So would it be a reasonable conclusion that the authors may have used this method at the time because it was the only one available to compute differences between groups?

Ultimately, is there a clear pedagogic example in which I should use one over the other?

Thanks a lot in advance!

*Permanova Results*

[image: Permanova results]

*Anosim Results*

[image: Anosim results]

Comment: This will not answer directly to your question but, considering PERMANOVA may be influenced by different within-group dispersion among them, have you tested this before?